# How can I Do OLEDB BulkCopy to insert bulkrecords?

Tags: c#

I have used SqlBulkCopy to insert bulkrecords into database. Now i want to change it as Oledb Connections. So i need to Change my bulkcopy..

How can i do same in the oledb?

```
SqlBulkcopy obj = new SqlBulkcopy("TableName");
```

Answer (score 3):

`SqlBulkCopy` uses a specific database feature, that has no *generic* OLEDB counterpart. Individual providers may have something similar, but you would have to use to provider-specific variant (or find a library that already wraps this, if one).

In short: as far as I know, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

SqlBulkCopy class is only designed to work with SQL Server database and works with SQlClient.

There is no counterpart in Oledb